# Underline doesn't display in Ooxml

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, openxml, word-addins

I am debugging a Word office js add-in. One thing that it needs to do is create a hidden section in the word document. To do this, I pass in some information to a javascript function that creates an OoXML string. I give the user the ability to embed some text in the section, and the user needs to be able to italicize, bold, underline or apply any combination of those formats to the embedded text. Italicization and bolding work fine, but underlining doesn't work.

The embedded text is entered into an html text box in the add-in. The user can click a button to italicize, another button to bold, a third button to underline, or a fourth button to remove those decorations. The click events of the buttons prepend and append html tags, so a string of text which is bolded, italicized and underlined would be sent over like this:

```
<b><i><u>string of text</u></i></b>
```

Then another function converts this to Ooxml. The resulting ooxml looks like this:

```
<w:r> <w:rPr> <w:b /> <w:i /> <w:u /> </w:rPr> <w:instrText xml:space="preserve">string of text</w:instrText> </w:r>
```

(I can see the ooxml string in my console log).

After the code inserts this into the document, it is bolded and italicized but not underlined. I have tried playing around with the function that generates the code, for example removing the space between the w:u and the />:

```
<w:r> <w:rPr> <w:b/>  <w:i/> <w:u/> </w:rPr> <w:instrText xml:space="preserve">string of text</w:instrText> </w:r>
```

I tried removing the trailing backslash on those tags but that broke the range.insertOoxml() call. I've also tried adding a w:val="single" attribute because I wasn't sure if the val was required or not, ie.:

```
<w:r> <w:rPr> <w:b />  <w:i /> <w:u w:val="single" /> </w:rPr> <w:instrText xml:space="preserve">string of text</w:instrText> </w:r>
```

I am stumped at this point. The code is agnostic as to what tag is used -- it doesn't care if it's a b, i or u. I understand that `<w:b />` and `<w:i />` are toggles and `<w:u />` may not be -- do I need to handle that differently? Has anyone else run into this issue, and is there something wrong with the Ooxml that someone could point out?

Thank you.

EDIT: To clarify, what I originally included was only the formatting of the text inside the hidden section. Below is the full OoXml the code creates. I am separating the code before and after the original formatted text so you can see where it fits in to the entire OoXml code:

Before the formatted text string:

```
<pkg:package xmlns:pkg='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage'><pkg:part pkg:name='/_rels/.rels' pkg:contentType='application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml' pkg:padding='512'><pkg:xmlData><Relationships xmlns='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships'><Relationship Id='rId1' Type='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument' Target='word/document.xml'/></Relationships></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part><pkg:part pkg:name='/word/document.xml' pkg:contentType='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml'><pkg:xmlData><w:document xmlns:w='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main' >
<w:body><w:p><w:r> <w:fldChar w:fldCharType='begin' /> </w:r> <w:r><w:rPr><w:color w:val='C00000'/></w:rPr><w:instrText xml:space="preserve">
"XE Startindex_1_id_000014_e"</w:instrText> </w:r>
```

The formatted text string:

```
<w:r> <w:rPr> <w:b /> <w:i /> <w:u /> </w:rPr> <w:instrText xml:space="preserve">string of text</w:instrText> </w:r>
```

After the formatted text string:

```
<w:r><w:rPr><w:color w:val='C00000'/></w:rPr><w:instrText xml:space="preserve">"XE Endindex_1_id_000014"</w:instrText> </w:r> <w:r> <w:fldChar w:fldCharType='end' /> </w:r></w:p></w:body></w:document></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part></pkg:package>
```

Comment: You appear to be writing this to a field code, but no information about *what kind of field* is provided - that could be a factor. Simplest way would be to create a document in Word (as a user) with the basic content (field). Format that as required (if the underline is even accepted!), save and close. Open the document in the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool and inspect the XML - see if/how it differs from what your code is generating.

Comment: Thank you Cindy. I was unaware of the Open XML SDK Productivity tool -- it's very helpful. I am working on your suggestion.

Comment: What I'm seeing is very weird. I can see (using Open XML SDK Productivity tool) both the <w:b> and <w:u> tags in the document if I use Word's bold and italicize function. I can see the <w:b> tag in my own generated code but the <w:u> tag simply isn't there. This despite verifying that the text to insert is showing the <w:u> tag immediately before I call: var range = context.document.getSelection(); range.insertOoxml(txt, "Start");

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While I'm not exactly sure about the requirements on the "hidden section", here are two variants of Open XML markup that Word will render as bolded, italicized, and underlined text.

Let's start with normal text, for which you would use a `w:t` element. The text below is not hidden, however. If you wanted to hide it, you'd have to add the `w:vanish` element to the `w:rPr`. In that case, Word will render a thin dotted line and not show the normal underline (which should not be used in professionally typeset documents anyhow).

```xml
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:b/>
          <w:i/>
          <w:u w:val="single"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>string of text</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
```

In your question, you are using the `w:instrText` element, which is normally part of a complex field. Thus, the next example shows a complex field:

```xml
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:b/>
          <w:i/>
          <w:u w:val="single"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:instrText>string of text</w:instrText>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
      </w:r>
      <!--
        Note that Word will insert a w:r with an error message (Bookmark not found)
        at this point, if you ever update fields.
        -->
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
```

The field code will not normally be shown, so the text is hidden. However, if you update fields, Word will show an error message where you put the field.

In your question, you did not include the `w:r` elements with the `w:fldChar` child elements, so your text will always be visible and also underlined. Further, Word will turn the `w:instrText` into a `w:t`, so you'll be back at my first example.

**Update 2020-03-12**

If you want to create an index, this is what you would see in Word if you used the built-in functionality to mark entries and insert an index and also showed paragraph marks:

[image: Word Index]

If you do not show paragraph marks, the fields used to mark the entries are hidden:

[image]

I've just formatted the text in the curly braces manually. The key thing to note is that this is an actual `XE` (index entry) field. So you need to produce the markup for an actual field (as shown in my second example) and make sure the field looks like this (using the first paragraph as an example):

```xml
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>This is some</w:t>
      </w:r>

      <!-- Your field begins here -->

      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> XE "</w:instrText>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:i/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:instrText>Defoe</w:instrText>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:instrText xml:space="preserve">, Daniel\; </w:instrText>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:b/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:instrText>Moby Dick</w:instrText>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:instrText xml:space="preserve">" </w:instrText>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
      </w:r>

      <!-- Your field ends here -->

      <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve"> text.</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
```

Note that you must escape colons (:) and semicolons (;) in the field code.

Comment: Hi Thomas and thanks for your reply. I edited my question so you can see the full context. I am already including w:fldChar begin and end elements.

Comment: Why was my answer downvoted? Happy to delete if it is deemed unhelpful.

Comment: @NedBalzer, why are you using the `w:instrText` element at all? This is for fields and you are trying to insert non-field text (so it seems at least).

Comment: I didn't downvote it, sorry, I think it has been helpful but still am trying to figure out the solution. I do not have sufficient reputation/cred on StackOverflow to up or downvote yet.

Comment: I did inherit this code from another programmer so I'm not sure why w:instrText is being used. This is my first OoXml and Word-js project. I'm happy to hear any other suggestions to improve the code -- it seems overly complex to me. I will try out some simpler things.

Comment: @NedBalzer, why don't you take a step back and tell us what the objective really is? If we understand your ultimate goal, we can suggest the correct Open XML markup for that. If it was OK to use the `w:instrText` to reach your goal, my second example would be correct.

Comment: The add-in I'm working on helps an author to index a book. An author can select a word, phrase or entire section (multiple pages) of the document. The author can then define a word or phrase that constitute an index entry.

Comment: In this example:
_Defoe_, Daniel; **Moby Dick**
the author enters this text into a textbox, highlights the title of the book, and bolds it, and italicizes Defoe. A process creates an entry consisting of start and end tags with the formatted text in between. The entry needs to be hidden so that the author can choose to see or not see it (by turning off/on paragraph marks.

Comment: Two subsequent processes A) scan the document for these tags and construct an index at the end with page placeholders, and B) finalize the index by resolving the page numbers (process B is a separate VSTO add-in since the word-js APIs cannot do that.)

Comment: The spec calls for not just **bold** and _italic_ but also underline (which I also can't do in this comment.)

Comment: Aha! The indexing piece was key. So, what you need to do is create index fields. From which Word can then create an index. I'll amend my answer to show an example.

Comment: Thomas this is fantastic information. I think the former programmer was implementing something like this. Is there somewhere I can read more about Word's built in indexing capabilities? I don't see the underlining issue addressed in your amended answer and I also don't understand the w:rsidRPr="00F37389" attribute -- is that something that Word creates on its own; IOW did you just use word to create a couple of index entries and then examine the resulting Ooxml? I need to make sure it meets all our requirements. I'll accept your answer too.

Comment: Here's the link I found: https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/word/how-to-build-an-index-in-word-2016/. The underline issue is addressed. I just picked the other example (because no professionally typeset document will use underlining, which is used to tell the typesetter to set the text in italics). If you want to underline, just add the proper tag to the `w:rPr` element. And, yes, I simply created the Word document and looked at the markup created by Microsoft Word. You don't have to produce the `w:rsidRPr` attributes. Word does that to keep track of editing sessions.

Comment: I found that same link. Interesting that the built in word References>Index>Mark Entry supports bold and italic for page number format, but not underline. I understand your point about typesetting though. Thanks for all your help -- I think I can take it from here.